# Computing probability 1 player win given both follow normal distribution with same standard deviation

Tags: probability, self-study

I am given that score ("logscore") of 2 players follow a normal distribution. They both have the same standard deviation of 0.205 but the mean varies. Player A has mean logscore that exceeds B by 0.15. I need to compute the probability A wins B. How do I approach this problem?

[image]

---

I think the its also very similar to the below question (e). How do I do such comparisons on 2 normal random variables?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider two variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$  (logscores in this particular case)

Note that $P(X_1>X_2)=P(X_1-X_2>0)$

So if you can work out the distribution of $X_1-X_2$, you can solve the problem easily.

The second problem doesn't have independence, so it's a little more complex, but the same strategy applies.